# In GTK3, how do I get a DrawingArea to respond keyboard events?

Tags: c, gtk3, keyboard-events, drawingarea

In GTK3, how do I get a DrawingArea to respond keyboard events?
Should I connect the DrawingArea with a signal or is it more compicated?
I'm using GTK3 with the C language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fianlly found the solution [here](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?242963-gtk-drawingarea-key-presses). I only connected the signal, but the GTK_CAN_FOCUS also need to be set for the drawingrea.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable key presses (and possibly also key releases) in the event mask:

```
gtk_widget_add_events(my_drawing_area, 
                      GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK|GDK_KEY_RELEASE_MASK);
```

Then you can connect to the signal(s):

```
g_signal_connect(my_drawing_area,"key-press-event", 
                 my_key_press,my_user_data);
g_signal_connect(my_drawing_area,"key-release-event",
                 my_key_release,my_user_data);
```

And define some callback functions like this:

```
gboolean my_key_press(GtkWidget *widget,
                      GdkEventKey *event,
                      gpointer user_data)
{
    return FALSE;
}

gboolean my_key_release(GtkWidget *widget,
                        GdkEventKey *event,
                        gpointer user_data)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

See documentation for [GtkWidget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event), [GObject Signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html) and [GdkEvent](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html) for more information.

Comment: It's just doesn't work:

`g_signal_connect(drawing_area, "button-press-event", 
  G_CALLBACK(button_press_event_callback), data);
g_signal_connect(drawing_area, "key-press-event", 
  G_CALLBACK(key_press_event_callback), data);
g_signal_connect(drawing_area, "key-release-event", 
  G_CALLBACK(key_press_event_callback), data);

gtk_widget_add_events(drawing_area,
                        GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK |
                            GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK |
                            GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK);`

Comment: I assume that not working means the callback never gets called. I'm not sure that it matters, but you may need to call `gtk_widget_add_events()` before connecting the signals. Otherwise it may be a focus problem, that the keypresses are sent to another widget. If you don't care about widget focus and simply want to catch all keypresses it might be a better idea to use the (toplevel) window instead of the drawing area.

Comment: I changed the order and the callback still doesn't get called. In the original code, the button-press-event works, so I think, the order doesn't matter. While I tested it, I clicked multiplie times to the widget to make sure that to focus is on the drawing_area. I only want to catch the keypresses when the focus is on the drawing_area.